# How to 'force' render javascript when using HTMLSession.render() during web scraping?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, geospatial

I need to scrape the postcode data from the website. https://www.pos.com.my/postal-services/quick-access/?postcode-finder#postcodeIds=01000

First I started with the usual BeautifulSoup workflow but later notice that some elements are not found despite being searchable when I inspect the page source code.

After a bit of research, I suspect that this is due to javascript behavior which renders a page dynamically.

I then follow the tutorial here http://theautomatic.net/2019/01/19/scraping-data-from-javascript-webpage-python/ and it works pretty well on this page 
https://www.pos.com.my/postal-services/quick-access/?postcode-finder#postcodeIds=50250

Naturally, I then proceed to loop over the possible range to extract the data from each page.

I found that the code behavior is not always consistent when I loop the same code across different pages.

For example, when I ran the code on this page
https://www.pos.com.my/postal-services/quick-access/?postcode-finder#postcodeIds=01000, the code fails to find the postcode table.

I've been toying around with the code to find an explanation but to no avail.

I suspect that maybe I need to somehow  refresh the javascript render each time or reset the browser session.

```py
# http://theautomatic.net/2019/01/19/scraping-data-from-javascript-webpage-python/

# import HTMLSession from requests_html
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# set 'root' url
rurl = 'https://www.pos.com.my/postal-services/quick-access/?postcode-finder#postcodeIds='
urls = []

for i in range(1000,99999):
    url = rurl + str(i).zfill(5)
    urls.append(url)

#for url in urls:
#    print(url)

# prepare file for output
filename = "MY_POS_Malaysia_postcodes.csv"
f = open(filename, "a+")
headers = "url,location, post_office, postcode_str, state\n"
f.write(headers)

# create an HTML Session object

for url in urls:
    print("Start session")
    session = HTMLSession()
    # Use the object above to connect to needed webpage
    resp = session.get(url)
    print(resp)
    # Run JavaScript code on webpage, so that the 'missing' elements are now shown
    resp.html.render()
    # create beautifulsoup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.html.html, "lxml")
    # look for tr elements (this assumes tr exclusively have postcodes information)
    # do sanity check 
    print("Start: " + url)
    postcodes = soup.find_all("tr")
    if len(postcodes) > 0 and len(postcodes[0]) == 9:
        print("Number of postcodes: " + str(len(postcodes)))
        for postcode in postcodes[1:len(postcodes)]:
            location = postcode.find_all('td')[0].text.strip()
            post_office = postcode.find_all('td')[1].text.strip()
            postcode_str = postcode.find_all('td')[2].text.strip()
            state = postcode.find_all('td')[3].text.strip()
            print("url: " + url)
            print("location: " + location)
            print("post_office: " + post_office) 
            print("postcode_str: " + postcode_str)
            print("state: " + state)
            print('Start writing...')
            f.write(url.replace(",", " ") + "," 
                + location.replace(",", " ") + "," 
                + post_office.replace(",", " ") + ","
                + postcode_str.replace(",", " ") + "," 
                + state + "\n")
            print('End writing')
        print("End: " + url)
    else:
        f.write(url + "," 
                + " " + "," 
                + " " + ","
                + " " + "," 
                + " " + "\n")
    session.close()
    print("Close session")

f.close()
```

For every page where the url exists, I want to extract the postcode tables and store it in a csv file.

I would also appreciate some ideas on how to get the actual existing urls instead of brute force searching from a range of numbers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using selenium instead of HTMLSession.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

#KL x
#wp kuala lumpur 284 https://www.pos.com.my/postal-services/quick-access/?postcodeFinderState=wp%20kuala%20lumpur&postcodeFinderLocation=&page=1000

# set 'root' url
rurl = 'https://www.pos.com.my/postal-services/quick-access/?postcodeFinderState=wp%20kuala%20lumpur&postcodeFinderLocation=&page='
urls = []

# generate urls
for i in range(1,284):
    url = rurl + str(i)
    urls.append(url)

# prepare file for output
filename = "MY_POS_Malaysia_postcodes_selenium_kl.csv"
f = open(filename, "a+")
headers = "url,record\n"
f.write(headers)

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    timeout = 30
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "postcode-container")))
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.quit()
    if WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "postcode-container"))):
        postcode_element = driver.find_element(By.ID,'postcode-container').text;
        #result -- Electronic Devices as the first category listing
        #  postcode_element.count('\n')
        # len(postcode_element.splitlines())
        # create postcodes array
        postcodes = postcode_element.splitlines()
        for postcode in postcodes:
            print(postcode)
            f.write(url + "," + postcode + "\n")


f.close()
```